# Composition of functions using injectivity

Tags: analysis, function-and-relation-composition

I am really stuck on the following question so any help would be appreciated.

a) Give an example of function f: A -> B and g: B -> A such that f ∘ g (y) = y for all y in B but where f is not injective.

b) Let f: A -> B and g: B -> A be two functions such that g ∘ f (x) = x for all x in A. Show that f is injective and f ∘ g(y) = y for all y in f(A).

I am really confused and I do not know how to work it out. 
Thank you!!

Comment: a) $\sin:\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$ and $\text{arcsin}:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Coolwater could you maybe think of a function that does not involve trig?

Comment: $\text{abs} : [-1,1] \to [0,1]$ and the identity $\mathbb{I} : [0,1] \to [-1,1]$. The thing is that $g$ doesn't need be surjective

Comment: @Coolwater I am still confused and would need more explanation... Also, what does ''abs'' mean?